# Stripe - Payment split but a fail happens, how to handle it?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

For my studying project, we implemented Stripe. From our app, you can buy stuff/services and split the price between users. However, we're facing a problem and we aren't sure to understand how to handle it.

Let's take this example:

> A, B and C are friends and they want to split a payment. A and B accept the transaction and get debited. However, C accept but the
>   payment gets refused because he doesn't have enough of money on is
>   account.

Since A and B were charged, then we have to refund, but then we lose money, so we would like to know if it's possible to check, before charging, if the user can pay or not.

We thought about eWallet but... My team doesn't really want to implement it for some personal reasons.

We're a bit stuck, does someone has any idea or just a tip?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3):

I think you could probably accomplish this with [Auth & Capture](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#auth-and-capture); i.e., Auth all 3 cards, and only proceed to Capture if all Auths are successful.

Comment: Thank for the edit and the answer, we'll take a look at it and come back to you soon :)